# Best Pratice on a quick SQL read from the DB in Sharepoint for a settings value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following code that I am using to pick up some quick settings for a small custom control that's used sparilingly each month.

I am worried that this isn't the best and quickest approach that will use the least resources.

Can I get someone to evaluate my statements and suggust improvemnts?

```
    public String getSettingVariable(string keyName)
    {
        var keyValue = String.Empty;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
        {
            string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IntFTRDB"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
            {
                if (sqlConn != null || sqlConn.State != ConnectionState.Open) sqlConn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "Select distinct Value where Name = @name";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = keyName;
                keyValue = (String)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        });
        return keyValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How many sql calls do you have in your application?  If just one or few, then the approach you are using is fine.  If your application plans on making several (100s) of calls into the database, then a more elegant solution would be need like building out a data access layer or using an ORM.

The use of `using` to automatically dispose of the connection and a parametized sql call is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Yeah for this app it's only about 5 calls total and maybe 25 in a session. It's a quick little interface page to copy data from a secure server to a less secure public site. Seems like I spend my whole life in these little one offs!